# roslyn update a Document with CompilationUnitSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I want to update a Document with a CompilationUnitSyntax in Roslyn.

Seems this was possible in older versions of Roslyn with the call:

```
//...
document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(compilationUnit);
```

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175115/4415401

However in the current version of Roslyn, this call seems to be removed:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=updatesyntaxroot

The DocumentExtensions class (where I would think such a method would be defined) is now internal too.

Is there some way I can do an UpdateSyntaxRoot on a document in Roslyn now?

Comment: using document.WithSyntaxRoot ?

Comment: nhabuiduc, thanks! Should have looked in Document.cs before asking the Q.